# How Pako library can gzip a request and send the GZIP_MAGIC that it can identify the request has been compress with gzip

Tags: java, angular, gzip, pako

This is application in Angular and Java.

Tha angular is compressing the request with pako library, like this :

```
  var compressedBody = pako.gzip(JSON.stringify(request.body))
  const clone = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.append('Content-Encoding', 'gzip'), body: compressedBody });
```

When the Backend is reading the request -> The request is compress but it doesn't come the
GZIP_MAGIC to identify the body has been request in gzip, so it's not unzip the request.

Can anybody know how to send the request in pako that I can receive the GXIP_MAGIC?

Thanks

```
CheckedInputStream in = new CheckedInputStream(this_in, crc);
crc.reset();
// Check header magic
if (readUShort(in) != GZIP_MAGIC) {
    throw new ZipException("Not in GZIP format");
}
```

readUShort(in) is 8752 and it should be GZIP_MAGIC=35615